# Somehow all products were deleted - Magento

Tags: php, mysql

This one is quite unusual.

A client was bulk deleting products from Magento (latest build) and somehow nearly all products were deleted.

Here is the client's description:

*Following a successful routine deletion of a batch of products a second attempt following the same procedure appears to have resulted in every product being deleted including those not selected for deletion.
Steps followed.
From the admin toolbar, “manage products” page was selected, then scrolled to page 34 out of 34. Then clicked select all, then de-selected each product i wanted to keep. Then selected delete from actions dropbox and clicked submit. The result was successful deletion of the products that had been selected for deletion.
The process was repeated for page 33 out of the remaining 33 pages. The command failed to process as indicated by the loading symbol in the browser bar continuing to rotate for about 4minutes before the command was terminated by clicking the loading symbol to halt the process. During this time it is possible that SSL certificates were being installed on the website by another user. When the page was later refreshed lthe majority of products from the site had been deleted from pages 1-33. Without any further commands to delete remaing products, as time passed more of the remaining products were deleted from the catalogue until all products were eventually deleted.*

Does anyone have any idea what may have happened here?

Many Thanks
Chris

Comment: Don't ever use **Select All**, those who get used to doing it will suffer the consequences as you must visit **every page** and deselect **all items on all pages** that you want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you click "Select all" on Products Grid it selects really all products, not only visible on current page: [see here](https://url.odesk.com/whpgrg)

Now your client needs to restore products from latest db backup

Comment: There are several landmines in the Magento interface that await the unwary and unobservant. You can and will completely empty your database of all product by using **Select All**. Any Grid where **Select All** will do the same for what it maintains. It's just as good as deleting one of your Root Categories over in Category Maintenance. It's why responsible Magento website owners do nightly database backups and database backups prior to **any major maintenance operation**. If you're going to be moving categories around, you can completely lose the website under certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks.  My client tells me this is different to the old version of Magento.

Comment: I was unaware that such a major operation was to be committed, else a backup would have been made! Thanks again

Comment: And it doesn't give you a "do you really want to do this as this is the end of the world" warning like it should. Magento does not follow GAAP rules and would anger most accountants with some of the things it does which are far worse than being able to delete cancelled Sales Orders, which it will not allow you to do. While the front end's purty, the backend shows a lack of knowledge with approved accounting practice and work process flow.